# Check if response is JSON in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I thought this would be simple, but I can't find how to do it.

All I want to do is write a spec that passes if a json file is returned instead of an HTML file.

This is what my test looks like right now:

```
    require 'spec_helper'

    describe "sessions" do
      before do
        @program =FactoryGirl.create(:program)
        @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      end

      describe "user" do
        it "is logged in" do
        post "/api/v1/login", user_login: {email: @user.email, password: @user.password }
        response.status.should be(201)
        # response.format.should be(:json) # Can I do something like this?
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Why do you care? The format isn't really worth testing, in my opinion. Instead, you can check whether the response contains the necessary data; the actual format used to transport the data is irrelevant.

Comment: I thought it would be the simplest way to know that my iOS app was getting the format it needed instead of an HTTP error page or something.

Comment: I want to make sure that I am getting the JSON response instead of a web page as a response. Since both would return 201, can you recommend what you would test for?

Comment: FYI, JSON-schema is an interesting tool for taking this further. You can check if the JSON has the right data in the right structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest You to check the actual content as meagar already noted. In my projects I have used this gem for easier matching: https://github.com/collectiveidea/json_spec

It provides handy matchers to easy match json content:
be_json_eql
include_json
have_json_path
have_json_type
have_json_size

```
response.body.should include_json("some_field: 'it definitely has'")
```

Comment: Got  MultiJson::LoadError: 795: unexpected token at 'success: 'true'' do i frogot something?